# Automatically add links from Amazon S3 files or Google Cloud Storage to Google Cloud SQL table

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to create a table in Google Cloud SQL that automatically updates with embed links from files that are added to certain buckets in Google Cloud Storage and Amazon S3. These will eventually be embedded in a website I'm building. I can't figure out where to even start getting these applications to talk to each other.

I've learned enough basic mySQL to work my way around the Google Cloud SQL interface, but I'm really very new to databases, so thanks in advance for your patience!

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you expect from and plan to do with a table that *"automatically updates with embed links from files that are added to certain buckets."*

Comment: Thanks Michael! Essentially I'd like to build a primitive version of Youtube with my own video files that are hosted on Amazon S3 or Google Cloud storage. I'd like to build a page that displays a number of embedded videos, and updates  when video files are added to a certain bucket in Amazon S3 or Google cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

Both AWS and GC have relatively straightforward mechanisms for getting bucket object event details back to a database.

S3 has [Event Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) which can (among other things) trigger an [AWS Lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) to insert information about the new object into your database.

GCS has [Cloud Pub/Sub Notifications for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) which can (among other things) trigger a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to insert information about the new object into your database.

In both environments, you can write the function for Node.js and instead of it running on servers, it's handled by automatically scaling containers.  On AWS, there is native support for some additional languages.